# After implementing .js file, not longer able to fill out textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, cordova

i'm working on an application for iOS7 (SinglePage Application, Cordova, Xcode5).

So, now i needed a slider which will allow the user to select a value between 0 and 20. For that i implented the nestoria slider (nstslider) into my project.

This is what my head area now looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqm-struc-1.4.3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.nstSlider.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqm-1.4.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nstSlider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() { 
            $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = 0;
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Now i have a registration script where the users can register an account on a server and for that i need the slider:

```
<div class="nstSlider" data-range_min="0" data-range_max="20" data-cur_min="5" data-cur_max="0">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="leftGrip"></div>
</div>
<div class="leftLabel"></div>
<script>
    $('.nstSlider').nstSlider({
        "left_grip_selector": ".leftGrip",
        "value_bar_selector": ".bar",
        "value_changed_callback": function(cause, leftValue, rightValue) {
            var $container = $(this).parent(),
            g = 150,
            r = 94,
            b = 33;
            $container.find('.leftLabel').text(leftValue);
            $(this).find('.bar').css('background', 'rgb(' + [r, g, b].join(',') + ')');
        }
    });
</script>
```

If i comment out the .js file for the slider, my textfields still work fine. But if i use it, i'm not able to click into the fields. Only if i click and hol my finger on my screen, after a short time (i have to take away my finger after 4 sek) the Keyboard opens and i'm able to enter Text into the textfield.

Is it my mistake, or is there sth wrong with the slider?

Thanks in advance!

PS: This is one of my textfields:

```
<input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Ihr Name" name="name" required></br>
            E-Mail Adresse*:</br>
```

Maybe it has sth to do with the onclick event (300ms delay)? If i just hold down the mouse shorter than a second, but longer than 500ms it opens up the keyboard
Okay, but i'm still not able to enter text into the text-fields

Comment: Have you at least checked the console for errors?

Comment: Yes, no errors inside it :-/

Comment: Have you tried opening nstslider's demo website in Safari on your iOS7 device: http://lokku.github.io/jquery-nstslider/. Does the slider work correctly there?

Comment: You are using jQuery Mobile in your project. Have you considered using JQM's Range Slider widget? http://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/ Or you're required to use nstslider widget in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem happens because the element that contains the slider works as a "panel" that is used to catch touch events to improve the "grabbability" of the sliders handles.

I've managed to reproduce your issue in the demo page, which looks like this: https://gist.github.com/darksmo/e13daceadb1c7905c285

To work around this, you can simply enclose the slider and your label markup (or even just the slider) with a **div** as shown here: https://gist.github.com/darksmo/da79b2d4f9b54a23e542

Comment: Note, the discussion is also appearing in the form of a bug report [on github](http://github.com/lokku/jquery-nstslider/issues/13).